# Count equal objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I've been trying to figure out a way of checking how many of a certain object are in an `NSArray`.

I've looked through the docs and I'm pretty sure there is no premade method for this. Also I can't find anything here on SO.

Do anybody know about a good way to do this? Because I seriously can't come up with anything.

In this specific case I have an array with strings (most cases several of each) and I want to count how many strings in the array that matches to  whatever I ask for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is a primary use of the data structure and order doesn't matter, consider switching to an `NSCountedSet` which is specifically for solving this problem efficiently.

If you need an ordered collection, and you don't have a huge set of objects, than the fast enumeration answers are the best approach.

If you want to know where the objects are, then use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

If you have a huge number of object, I would look at `indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:` with the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option. This will allow you to search the array on multiple cores. (This is only possibly faster on a multi-core device, and even then is probably only faster if you have a very large collection. You should absolutely test before assuming that concurrent will be faster.) Even if you just need the final count, it *may* be faster for certain data sets to use this method and then use `count` on the final index set.

Comment: Really good and educational answer! However I already checked someone else... Vote up though for the effort and greatness of it!

Comment: @user1534948 You shouldn't check the first answer but the answer that gave the most correct answer (which, in my humble opinion, is this one). There is nothing wrong with checking a newer, more complete, answer.

Comment: Good point. Was doubtful basically because I already had used the other one before this even was posted.
Although I guess this will help more future searchers.

Comment: yeah, this definitely should've been the accepted answer. i bet a lot of folks who have been working with ios for some time (like myself) don't know this either!

Answer (score 8):

There actually is a method for this: `- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate`

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqualTo:myOtherObject];
}];
```

Comment: Oh man, I was looking for that method but I could only find it in NSSet. No idea why!

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a case for `NSCountedSet`, which does what you are after with its `initWithArray:` initializer:

```
// Example array of strings
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Joe", @"Jane", @"Peter", @"Paul",
                  @"Joe", @"Peter", @"Paul",
                  @"Joe",
                  @"Jane", @"Peter",
                  nil];

NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray: array];

// for-in will let you loop over the counted set
for (NSString *str in countedSet) {
    NSLog(@"Count of %@: %ld", str, (long)[countedSet countForObject:str]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to iterate and check.

```
- (int)repeatsOf:(NSString *)repeater inArray:(NSArray *)array {
    int count = 0;

    for (NSString *item in array) {
        if ([item isEqualToString:repeater]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a simple loop. Suppose `needle` is your reference string and `array` is your NSArray of strings:

```
unsigned int n = 0;

for (NSString * str in array)
{
    if ([needle isEqualToString:str])
    {
        ++n;
    }
}
```

Now `n` holds the count of strings in equal to `needle`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function like this:

```
- (int)countStringsThatMatch:(NSString*)match inArray:(NSArray*)array
{
    int matches = 0;

    for (id string in array) {
        if ([string isEqualToString:match]) {
            matches++;
        }
    }

    return matches;    
}
```

And then use it like:

```
int count = [self countStringsThatMatch:@"someString" inArray:someArray];
```

Comment: You have no idea of how tupid i feel for not coming up with that myself... ^^
I'll just try it out, and you got the check!

Comment: we all get stuck on really simple things every now and then, don't sweat it!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSUInteger) objectCountInArray:(NSArray *)array 
                   matchingString:(NSString *)stringToMatch {
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        count += [string isEqualToString:stringToMatch] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return count;
}
```

You can try to expand this to use a block that gets an object and returns a BOOL. Then you can use it to compare an array of whatever you want.